# Inline arrow function click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html code:

```
<button id ="btn-birthdate" class = "mdc-icon-button material-icons" >
    <i class="material-icons" >stop</i>
</button>
```

This is my javascript code

```
const displayExtraUserInfo  = (userInfo) => {
    const btn = () => {
        document.querySelector('btn-birthdate').onclick = displayBirthdate(UserInfo);
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the message

> You have not created the `onclick` listener for the `btn-birthdate` as
>   specified

...when I run in Sapio

**Question am trying to solve**

> Create a `displayExtraUserInfo` arrow function. It should take in a single parameter. It should then:
>
> Add an inline arrow function click listener to the BUTTON with id of `btn-birthdate`. The listener should make a call to `displayBirthdate` and pass in the parameter `displayExtraUserInfo` received

Answer (score 4):

In the `onclick` assignment you are currently *executing* `displayBirthdate` immediately, instead of assigning a function.

So change

```
.onclick = displayBirthdate(UserInfo)
```

to:

```
.onclick = () => displayBirthdate(UserInfo)
```

On the other hand, you never call the `btn` function after having defined it. Either add a call `btn()` or just don't define that function at all, and just execute its code inline.

There is also a problem with the selector. You are selecting an element of which the tag name is `btn-birthdate`, but you should select by the id. `#btn-birthdate`.

And there is yet another mistake: the spelling of `userInfo` should be consistent, otherwise you are dealing with another variable.

So the final solution would be:

```
const displayExtraUserInfo = (userInfo) => {
    document.querySelector('#btn-birthdate').onclick = () => displayBirthdate(userInfo);
}
```

Finally, the question says you are looking for a button. Although an element id is supposed to be unique, you could add the `button` in the selector:

```
const displayExtraUserInfo = (userInfo) => {
    document.querySelector('button#btn-birthdate').onclick = () => displayBirthdate(userInfo);
}
```

Comment: I have done so but am still getting the error message when run in Sapio

Comment: I have done so but am still getting the error message when run in Sapio

Comment: Which is the error message? Did you call `btn` at all? If not, see addition to my answer.

Comment: **You have not created the onclick listener for the btn-birthdate button as specified**

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: I initially did this like this, but I will try it again

Comment: may be you should help me read the question, maybe I am missing something........**Create a displayExtraUserInfo arrow function. It should take in a single parameter. It should then:

Add an inline arrow function click listener to the BUTTON with id of btn-birthdate. The listener should make a call to displayBirthdate and pass in the parameter displayExtraUserInfo received**

Comment: Found a few more problems in your code. Please see update.

Answer (score 0):

The querySelector method uses CSS selector formatting, so `querySelector('btn-birthdate')` is not going to find anything. You need `querySelector('#btn-birthdate')` to target the id "btn-birthdate".

You could also use `document.getElementById("btn-birthdate")`

Comment: have done this already........................may be you should help me read the question, maybe I am missing something........*Create a displayExtraUserInfo arrow function. It should take in a single parameter. It should then: Add an inline arrow function click listener to the BUTTON with id of btn-birthdate. The listener should make a call to displayBirthdate and pass in the parameter displayExtraUserInfo received*

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```js
const displayExtraUserInfo = (userInfo) => {
        document.getElementById('btn-birthdate').addEventListener('click',()=>{
          displayBirthdate(userInfo)
        } );
```